# Criar botão via código

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

É possível criar um `Button` por meio do código, ao invés do modo design (xml)?

Por exemplo: Vou criar uma tela com um `EditText`, digitar um número, e clicar em um `Button`.

Após isso, será criado *x* (número digitado) `EditText` abaixo do botão.

Comment: Já deu uma olhada na documentação oficial do Google ? É muito boa, acho que você conseguirá tirar sua dúvida !

Comment: Sim, já olhei e não achei nada específico a respeito :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primeiramente você precisa definir onde irá colocar seu botão (um container, por exemplo):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_teste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Texto" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Após isso, em seu código você pode adicionar um `Button` para este container:

```
FrameLayout container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_button);

//Criando um botão passando o contexto
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
button.setText("Algum texto");

//Adicionando o botão na tela
container.addView(button);
```

Comment: Deu certo. Muito obrigado